# How to change the glyph or icon for geom_abline in the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Im following this example [Add regression line legend to geom_abline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760519/add-regression-line-legend-to-geom-abline)

Is there a reason the legend line is slanting? Is it possible for the legend to have a straight red and blue line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You can choose the glyph for the legend with argument `key_glyph`. To get lines choose `key_glyph = "path"` in both `geom_abline` layers.

```r
set.seed(1234)
X <- rnorm(20,sd=2.5)
y <- -1+0.5*X+rnorm(20, sd=0.4)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = X, y = y)) + 
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = -0.9930872, slope = 0.4866284, colour = "line1"), lwd=1, key_glyph = "path") + 
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = -1, slope = 0.5, colour = "line2"), lwd=1, key_glyph = "path") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("line1"="red","line2"="blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I have modified the code to be the same as yours but its still on an angle rather than straight geom_abline(aes(colour="line3", intercept = -7.8, slope = 390, key_glyph = "path")) It says Ignoring unknown aesthetics: key_glyph

Comment: Don't put the `key_glyph = "path"` inside the `aes()`, .i.e. use `geom_abline(aes(colour="line3", intercept = -7.8, slope = 390), key_glyph = "path")`. (;